# Discord Google Image Search

Tags: discord.js, google-image-search

I am trying to make a discord bot where I search for "example image" and it takes a random image from google under that search term and sends it.

This is what I have so far:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
 
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
 
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'image':
        image(message);
 
        break;
    }
 
});
 
function image(message){
 
    var options = {
        url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + "example image",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome"
        }
    };
 
 
 
 
 
    request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
        if (error) {
            return;
        }
  
 
        $ = cheerio.load(responseBody); 
 
 
        var links = $(".image a.link");
 
        var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));
        
        console.log(urls);
 
        if (!urls.length) {
           
            return;
        }
 
        // Send result
        message.channel.send( urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
    });
```

and it works but dogpile doesn't give some images for some reason, so basically I tried everything to make it search in google instead of dogpile but it doesn't work.

TLDR: How do I search in google instead of dogpile.

Comment: Please give us more information rather than "it doesn't work". Some debugging details would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use npm [image-search-google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-search-google) package.

Comment: Tried to use it didn't work, maybe I was doing something wrong?